# Can size of an array be determined at runtime?

Tags: c++, arrays

The code [compiles and runs](http://rextester.com/RSSE82465), but is it legal? AFAIK, size of static array must be known at compile time.

```
#include <iostream>
void foo(const unsigned size){
    double arr[size];
    for(auto& i:arr){
        i=2;
        std::cout << i;
    }
}

int main(){
    unsigned size;
    std::cin >> size;
    foo(size);
}
```

Comment: But `arr` is not static...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "static" array??? The array in your example is local (automatic), not static.

Comment: @AndreyT by `static` I mean non-dynamic.

Comment: GingerPlusPlus, I think you should edit your question, `static` does not have the meaning that you think.

Comment: Just use `std::vector`.

Comment: @AndreyT I have no idea how can I improve the title, please edit my question if you think you can improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is not legal. ***Variable length arrays (VLA)*** are not supported by standard C++. VLA are supported by most compilers an an extension but using those may give you non portable behavior.

Also, there is no `static` array in your source code. To do so you would need to use the `static` keyword on the declaration.

Comment: IIRC Runtime-sized arrays are included in C++14.

Comment: @user657267, I believe they were cut towards the end, n3797 §8.3.4/1 has the size as a constant expression

Comment: So, avoid constructions like that?

Comment: @Niall wasn't that `std::dynarray`? Or were they both axed?

Comment: @user657267, both. See the note at the top of this page as well; http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray

Comment: @Niall right you are, here's the [TS](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3820.html).

Answer (score 1):

As user657267 mentioned, Runtime-size arrays have been discussed for C++14 in [N3639](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3639.html) and another similar feature, [std::dynarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray) has been discussed, however they have been rejected for C++14.

Currently, this is not considered as part of the standard although some compilers implemented this as non-portable extensions, gcc for example is one of these compilers (possibly because this is legal in C99).

Most of the time, you can just use a vector to the same effect.

Comment: I was wrong, VLAs and `std::dynarray` have been moved to a separate TS and are not part of C++14.

Comment: Yeah I saw that after, but was the decision final ?

Comment: Yeah I linked the [TS](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3820.html) in the other comments.

Answer (score 0):

In your example there is no array with the static storage duration. There is a local array within a function with automatic storage duration.
The size of the array shall be a constant expression.

If the code you showed is compiled then it means it is a feature of the compiler that supports Variable Length Arrays in C++ the same way as in C.